# "Error: Failed to detect OS" with Node.js on VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract.js to do OCR, but when I change exampleImage, I get this error. I can't find any information at all about this error. Thank you in advance.

app.js

```
const exampleImage = 'https://d1q6f0aelx0por.cloudfront.net/product-logos/5431a80b-9ab9-486c-906a-e3d4b5ccaa96-hello-world.png';
const Tesseract=require('tesseract.js');
const worker = Tesseract.createWorker({
  logger: m => console.log(m)
});
Tesseract.setLogging(true);
work();

async function work() {
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
  await worker.initialize('eng');

  let result = await worker.detect(exampleImage);
  console.log(result.data);

  result = await worker.recognize(exampleImage);
  console.log(result.data);

  await worker.terminate();
}
```

Console.log

```
Error: Failed to detect OS
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\Example\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:173:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage and their documentations use cases not matching did you check their documentation?

- https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/examples.md

Try to write like them for example;

```
const { createWorker } = require('tesseract.js');
const exampleImage = 'https://d1q6f0aelx0por.cloudfront.net/product-logos/5431a80b-9ab9-486c-906a-e3d4b5ccaa96-hello-world.png';

const worker = createWorker({
  logger: m => console.log(m), // Add logger here
});

(async () => {
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
  await worker.initialize('eng');
  const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(exampleImage);
  console.log(text);
  await worker.terminate();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was using too small of an image. With a larger image, the code worked fine.

Comment: What size does it require?